# SQL cmd login failed

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

I am trying to execute a large `.sql` file using `sqlcmd`. I can easily access the `sa` account through SSMS with the correct password. However, I am getting a

> Login failed for user 'sa'

error when using `sqlcmd`.

Commands tried:

```
sqlcmd -S servername\SQLEXPRESS -U sa -P REDACTED -d dbname -i C:\sample.sql

osql -S servername\SQLEXPRESS -U sa -P REDACTED -d dbname -i C:\sample.sql

sqlcmd -S "servername\SQLEXPRESS" -U "sa" -P "REDACTED" -d "dbname" -i "C:\sample.sql"
```

Comment: What happens if you just try to login without specifying the script and database?

Comment: Did you turn on the SQL Server authentication mode?

Comment: Hello, if you are referring to [server]>properties>security>SQL Server and Windows Auth. Mode, then yes. Thanks!

Comment: @RichardCrossley I tried that earlier, if gives me 1>

Comment: That means the connection parameters on the command line work. Try adding -d dbname and checking with each parameter until it fails.

Comment: @RichardCrossley `sqlcmd -S servername\SQLEXPRESS -U sa -P REDACTED -d dbname`  Gives me a Login failed / Cannot open database dbname requested by login. The login failed.

`sqlcmd -S servername\SQLEXPRESS -U sa -P REDACTED  -i  C:\filename.sql` gives me a lot of invalid object name.

Comment: What happens if you just login without the -d parameter and then type `use dbname`? I'm suspicious that the database you're trying to use can't be used by the 
"sa" for some reason. Is it offline?

Comment: @RichardCrossley I've recreated the dbname and it seemed to have worked. Thank you!

Comment: I've made that the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if you just login without the -d parameter and then type use dbname? I'm suspicious that the database you're trying to use can't be used by the "sa" for some reason. Is it offline?